# Как в архитектуре Документ-Вид в MFC создать список?

Tags: mfc, шаблоны-проектирования, c++

Документ должен содержать название группы, список фамилий и имен студентов группы в порядке возрастания их номеров, а также средний балл ECTS (0-100) и количество пропусков занятий для каждого из студентов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MFC есть шаблонный класс CList, помещаете объект этого класса в CDocument.